# Building a Phonegap application - recommended frameworks ?

Tags: cordova

I'm giving Phonegap a try and building a first application with it. I have a web background. Since I'm new to the phonegap SDK, I'm trying to think what is the best way to build an app for it (since it's not a regular web server and actually an application I have no idea to the behaviour and limitations of the platform).

What would you recommend to do while building a phonegap application - these are my thoughts:

1. just regular html pages which link to each other and js files for each html page with the logic for that page - but wouldn't that show like a refresh while moving between pages?
2. using AngularJS - with all it's advantages - but isn't it a bit of an overkill?

Which UI do you think is the best for building an application? I was thinking about Bootstrap 3 and combining elements from jquery-mobile?

Thanks

Comment: jquery-mobile on phonegap/cordova has given a lot of people trouble in the past, browse through some questions on this site to see the issues people have. Generally it seems like a huge library to include. For your first question, yeah it would show a refresh when moving between pages which is why people usually build Single Page Applications and then use some transition animations. While SO isn't the place to really suggest tools or libraries, I saw this brand new one a few days ago and want to try it out this weekend: http://ionicframework.com/ I'm not going to make any recommendations tho..

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

A PhoneGap application it is a regular web application wrapped in a native container. The biggest parts of it usually work fine on any browser, there is not much to consider in that regard when choosing a framework.

The only thing that is really different is that you can load your web pages from the local disk - which is much faster than over the network. So the size of a framework is negligible (but [speed isn't](http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/)).

A single page application framework like Angular or Backbone is what I would recommend. They come a lot closer to the feel of a native app and that's what users usually want. They are also faster to process because they only re-render the parts that change. You can compare various frameworks at [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/), but it's often best to simply use what you are already familiar with (Angular).

I worked on a jQuery mobile app for some time and it's been a terrible experience. It is easy to get something fairly usable done fast, but it caused problems when trying to do something dynamically without re-loading the page. Interface elements are enhanced by jQuery mobile on page load, so you have to call a lot of enhancement functions that don't even work reliably in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm jquery mobile is fine but I came accross this : http://onsenui.io/ a few days back (you need to have a good understanding of angular to use it), and use it check this https://github.com/malikov/simple-angular-phonegap-app to see how. I think it depends on the type of app you're building and how you code this thing when it comes to performance there's several things to consider see this stackoverflow post : [Angular.js Backbone.js or which has better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458436/angular-js-backbone-js-or-which-has-better-performance) . Hope this helps